# Can't run vagrant up

Tags: virtualbox, vagrant

I got an error when running `vagrant up`

```
The provider 'virtualbox' that was requested to back the machine
'booking_machine' is reporting that it isn't usable on this system. The
reason is shown below:

VirtualBox is complaining that the kernel module is not loaded. Please
run `VBoxManage --version` or open the VirtualBox GUI to see the error
message which should contain instructions on how to fix this error.
```

Then I run command `VBoxManage --version`. Here is the output

```
WARNING: The vboxdrv kernel module is not loaded. Either there is no module
         available for the current kernel (4.13.0-32-generic) or it failed to
         load. Please recompile the kernel module and install it by

           sudo /sbin/vboxconfig

         You will not be able to start VMs until this problem is fixed.
```

Tried `sudo /sbin/vboxconfig`, but still got error

```
vboxdrv.sh: Stopping VirtualBox services.
vboxdrv.sh: Building VirtualBox kernel modules.
vboxdrv.sh: failed: Look at /var/log/vbox-install.log to find out what went wrong.

There were problems setting up VirtualBox.  To re-start the set-up process, run
  /sbin/vboxconfig
as root.
```

Part of the output of `/var/log/vbox-install.log`

```
make KBUILD_VERBOSE=1 SUBDIRS=/tmp/vbox.0 SRCROOT=/tmp/vbox.0 CONFIG_MODULE_SIG= -C /lib/modules/4.8.0-41-generic/build -j2 modules
make[1]: warning: -jN forced in submake: disabling jobserver mode.
test -e include/generated/autoconf.h -a -e include/config/auto.conf || (        \
echo >&2;                           \
echo >&2 "  ERROR: Kernel configuration is invalid.";       \
echo >&2 "         include/generated/autoconf.h or include/config/auto.conf are missing.";\
echo >&2 "         Run 'make oldconfig && make prepare' on kernel src to fix it.";  \
echo >&2 ;                          \
/bin/false)
mkdir -p /tmp/vbox.0/.tmp_versions ; rm -f /tmp/vbox.0/.tmp_versions/*
make -f ./scripts/Makefile.build obj=/tmp/vbox.0
  gcc -Wp,-MD,/tmp/vbox.0/linux/.SUPDrv-linux.o.d  -nostdinc -isystem /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/include  -I./arch/x86/include -I./arch/x86/include/generated/uapi -I./arch/x86/include/generated  -I./include -I./arch/x86/include/uapi -I./include/uapi -I./include/generated/uapi -include ./include/linux/kconfig.h -Iubuntu/include  -D__KERNEL__ -fno-pie -Wall -Wundef -Wstrict-prototypes -Wno-trigraphs -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -Werror-implicit-function-declaration -Wno-format-security -std=gnu89 -fno-PIE -fno-pie -no-pie -mno-sse -mno-mmx -mno-sse2 -mno-3dnow -mno-avx -m64 -falign-jumps=1 -falign-loops=1 -mno-80387 -mno-fp-ret-in-387 -mpreferred-stack-boundary=3 -mskip-rax-setup -mtune=generic -mno-red-zone -mcmodel=ke
```

Comment: What's in `/var/log/vbox-install.log` ?

Comment: @meta I have added the output of `vbox-install.log`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found, how to fix that.
I have to intall the latest version of vagrant and virtualbox. Both!!!

Answer (score 0):

I remember having similar issues when switching between different kernels on my distro. The only solution that worked for me to reinstall virtualbox

```
sudo apt install virtualbox
```

AFAIR The reinstallation would trigger reconfiguration and should end up with proper modules (maybe restart would be required)

Comment: then you could accept the answer or upvote to mark it as helpful @Headmaster

Comment: I will, after I run `vagrant up` and fully check working ability

Comment: Then, how did you conclude that it helped?

Comment: there is no more that error, but command `vagrant up` freezes my PC